# A heap has corrupted after I free it C

Tags: c, heap-corruption

I have a struct of 2 pointers (shown below), which means 8 bytes.

```
struct DNS_query
{
    uint8_t* name;
    DNS_question* question;
};
```

So that means, when I allocate the place in the heap I allocate 8 * < constant value >. Then I go through the array and change the pointers' value, so it's still 8 bytes, but when I try freeing the memory I get the error "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after the end of heap buffer".

```
    DNS_query* query = (DNS_query*)malloc(ntohs(dns.questions) * sizeof(DNS_query));

    for (int i = 0; i < ntohs(dns.questions); i++)
    {
        query[i].name = (uint8_t*)&qDNS[sizeof(IP_header) + sizeof(UDP_header) + sizeof(DNS_header) + sizeof(DNS_query) * i];
        query[i].question = (DNS_question*)&raw_packet[sizeof(DNS_header) + (strlen((const char*)query[i].name) + 1)];
    }

    free(query);
```

Does that mean I changed more than 8 bytes and if so, how?

**This is of course only a part of the code but it is the part that troubles me**

Edit:
the application is being ran on a 32-bit system.

Comment: Step 1: Work through this in a debugger.

Comment: Why are you doing `ntohs` so many times? Do it once, save it to a variable. This makes debugging easier since you can inspect that value directly without having to do the conversion.

Comment: That name code is flat-out wrong, it makes enormous assumptions about the structure of the data. In a DNS packet the name can and *will* contain pointers. Read [RFC1035](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035) very carefully. The DNS protocol is fairly simple superficially, but there's some quirks under the surface you must be aware of.

Comment: It could mean that the corruption happened long before this code executed. valgrind can help you find out if an invalid write (or even read) happened before this code is reached.

Comment: Your assumption that "two pointers mean eight bytes" only applies on 32-bit systems.  On 64-bit systems (which are very common these days), the structure would use sixteen bytes.  Beware!

Comment: Posting enough code, at least, so we may compile it, would improve this question.

Comment: I would like to, but unfortunately, that means I have to upload the entire project, which uses libs like pcap.

Comment: @LeoSegol You will have to minimize and isolate the problem.